# Finding average of two variables in two equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

The given equations are:

$$7x+3y=17$$
and
$$3x+7y=19$$

How can i find the average of two variables $x$ and $y$ with simple calculation steps?

Comment: Just add the equations..............

Comment: Well, do you want to it the laborious but obvious way that will always work, or do you want to do it the slightly insightful and easy way.  The obvious way is to *solve* for $x$ and $y$ and take the average.  The insightful way is to add the two equations to but $10x + 10y = 36$ and divide by $20$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

adding two equations we get

$$10x+10y=36$$

than,

$$x+y=3.6$$

therefore,
the average of two variable $x/2+y/2$

$$3.6/2=1.8.$$

Answer (score 0):

Since we got two (differing from each other) formulas with only 2 unknown numbers, we can quite easily calculate both $x$ and $y$. I'll explain my steps, without using matrices, just algebra (just like you asked).

So, we got $7x + 3y = 17$ and $3x + 7y = 19$. Because we can say $17 = 19 - 2$ we can state that 
$$7x + 3y = 3x + 7y - 2$$
We take away $3x$ and $3y$ on both sides and we get
$$4x = 4y - 2$$
We divide both sides by $4$ and we get
$$x = y - \frac{1}{2}$$
Now, if we use that in our first equation, it becomes
$$7(y - \frac{1}{2}) + 3y = 17$$
$$7y - 3\frac{1}{2} + 3y = 17$$
We add $ 3\frac{1}{2}$ on both sides and it says
$$10y = 20\frac{1}{2}$$
Now we divide both sides by 10, and we calculated $y$!
$$y = 2\frac{1}{20}$$
And since we already know that $x = y - \frac{1}{2}$ we calculated that 
$$x = y - \frac{1}{2} = 2\frac{1}{20} - \frac{10}{20} = 1\frac{11}{20}$$
Now, if you still want the average, it is 
$$\frac{x + y}{2} = \frac{2\frac{1}{20} + 1\frac{11}{20}}{2} = \frac{72}{40} = 1\frac{32}{40} = 1\frac{4}{5}$$

There you go

EDT: Whoops, looks like I made a mistake somewhere since the answer is not correct, but you get the idea.
EDT2: Corrected the mistake (typo) thanks to the comments :) and this is in accordance with the answer placed by the question asker himself, so that's entirely correct!

Comment: Mistake here: $7(y - \frac{1}{2}) + 3y = 17
\stackrel{?}{\implies} 7y - 3\frac{1}{2} = 17$. It can be done more simply anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I just corrected it

Comment: maximum time to solve this kind of problem is less than a minute. so i am here to find the quick solution only so please suggest or give some quick ideas to solve these kind of problems..